# dompdf line heigth different from source

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I am trying to create a pdf using dompdf v0.6.1-4. However i ran into the following weirdness when creating the pdf. The line height looks to be completely ignored by dompdf on a table. Every row gets like a 100 pixel height. That is not how i want it to be.

Here is the html

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
 <title>
 voucher pdf
 </title>
 <style>

#wrapper{
 width: 800px;
 background-color: white;
}

#vouchercode{
 font-weight: bolder;
}

#customerlogo img{
 width: 400px;
 height: 285px;
}

#topleftimgdescr{
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#maxwifihref{
 text-align: center;
}

#maxwifiimg img{
 width: 170px;
 height: 75px;
}

#nl{
 height: 130px;
}

.countrytext{
 margin-left: 8px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.countrypng{
 width: 60px;
}

.partial{
 height: 140px;
}

.instruction{
 margin-left: 60px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 14px;
}

ul {
 margin-top: 0px;
}
#pagebreak{
 page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="5" width="400px" colspan="1" style="text-align: center;">
    <img id="customerlogo" src="./assets/images/logo_krieghuus.png" alt="" /><br />
    <label style="text-align: center;" id="topleftimgdescr">Vakantiepark de &ldquo;Krieghuusbelten&rdquo;</label>
   </td>
   <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;">
    <img id="maxwifilogo" src="./assets/images/maxwifi.png"  alt="" /><br />
    <label id="maxwifihref" style="margin-right: 50px;"><a>www.maxCoax.nl</a></label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
   <td colspan="3">Wifi activationcode</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
   <td colspan="1">Tijdsduur: </td><td colspan="2" id="timelimit">10080 minuten</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px;">
   <td colspan="1">Apparaten: </td><td colspan="2">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 25px; line-heigth: 12px;">
   <td colspan="1">Activatiecode: </td><td colspan="2" id="vouchercode">PnBndxTvYhu</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <div id="instructionsection">
  <div class="partial">
   <div class="countrypng"><img id="nllogo" src="./assets/images/plate.png" alt="" /><div class="countrytext">NL</div></div>
   <div class="instruction">
    <b>Instructies</b>
    <ul>
     <li>
     Start uw notebook, PDA of PC. Wanneer u binnen het bereik van een wifi hotspot bent kunt u verbinding<br />
     maken met het Wifi netwerk. Start internet en de activatiepagina opent.
     </li>
     <li>
      Vul de hierboven vermelde toegangscode in.
     </li>
     <li>
      De tijdsduurgebruik gaat in na activatie.
     </li>
     <li>
      U kunt gebruik maken van internet.
     </li>
     <li>
      <b>Let op!</b> Deze toegangscode is te activeren op 1 apparaat.
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="partial">
   <div class="countrypng"><img id="enlogo" src="./assets/images/plate.png" alt="" /><div class="countrytext">EN</div></div>
   <div class="instruction">
    <b>Instructions</b>
    <ul>
     <li>
     Start up your notebook, PDA or PC. Please connect with the Wifi network if you are within range of a Wifi access point.
     </li>
     <li>
      Log on to the internet. You will land on the activation page.
     </li>
     <li>
      Enter the above mentioned access code. The duration of use starts after activation.
     </li>
     <li>
      You are now ready to use internet.
     </li>
     <li>
      <b>Attention!</b> This code is for use on 1 device
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="partial">
   <div class="countrypng"><img id="delogo" src="./assets/images/plate.png" alt="" /><div class="countrytext">&nbsp;D</div></div>
   <div class="instruction">
    <b>Hinweise</b>
    <ul>
     <li>
     Starten Sie Ihr Notebook, PDA oder Ihren PC. Wenn Sie sich innerhald der Reichweite eines Accespoints befinden,<br />
     dan k&ouml;nnen Sie mit dem drahlosen Netzwerk verbindung machen.<!--haha, machen! -->
     </li>
     <li>
      Starten Sie internet. Sie bekommen den Aktivierungsseite.
     </li>
     <li>
      Geben Sie den oben erw&auml;hnten Aktivierungscode ein. Die Dauerder Anwenung startet nach den Aktivierung.
     </li>
     <li>
      Sie k&ouml;nnen jetzt das Internet benutzen.
     </li>
     <li>
      <b>Achtung<!-- ik ga helemaal stuk hier!-->!</b> Dieser code k&ouml;nnen sie gleichzeitig aktiveren f&uuml;r den Einsatz auf 1 Ger&auml;t.
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pagebreak" class="partial">
   <div class="countrypng"><img id="frlogo" src="./assets/images/plate.png" alt="" /><div class="countrytext">FR</div></div>
   <div class="instruction">
    <b>Instructions</b>
    <ul>
     <li>
     Ouvrez Votre portable, PDA ou PC. Lorsque vous &ecirc;tes dans les environs d&rsquo;un point d&rsquo;acc&egrave;s Wifi, vous serez reli&eacute;s<br />
     apr&egrave;s quelques secondes automatique au r&eacute;sea Wifi systeme sans fil.
     </li>
     <li>
      D&eacute;marrez internet. Alors sur le site du hotel ou camping.
     </li>
     <li>
      Compl&eacute;tez le code d&rsquo;acc&egrave;s mentionn&eacute; ci-dessus. La dur&eacute;e d&rsquo;utilisation commence apr&egrave;s l&rsquo;activation.
     </li>
     <li>
      Vous pourrez maintenant utiliser internet.
     </li>
     <li>
      <b>Attention!</b> Ce code est utilis&eacute; sur 1 p&egrave;riph&egrave;rique
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try implementing inline style, see if that helps.

Comment: i have already implemented that

Comment: Style doesn't work in tr, apply style on td. that will work

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/670

Comment: when i set it at the td, there is no difference sadly. I really need this to work...

Comment: When I render the HTML it looks fairly close to the browser rendering. Can you post screen shots of what it looks like?

Comment: i think it was due to the fact that i used a table with an image. The image td had a rowspan of 4. The other rows seem to have an height about 1/4 of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Table support in dompdf is acceptable but not very advanced and so complex table layouts can render poorly in dompdf. You might try simplifying your document as much as possible (e.g. by removing colspan/rowspan which do not appear to be necessary).

For example, the following renders a bit better.

```css
  #wrapper{
 width: 800px;
 background-color: white;
  }
  
  #vouchercode{
 font-weight: bolder;
  }
  
  #topleftimgdescr{
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  #maxwifihref{
 text-align: center;
  }
  
  #nl{
 height: 130px;
  }
  
  .countrytext{
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .partial{
 margin-top: 2em;
 min-height: 140px;
 page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  
  .instruction{
 font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
  <title>
    voucher pdf
  </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="400px" style="text-align: center;">
        <img id="customerlogo" src="http://placehold.it/400x285/cc6666/ffffff&text=dompdf"><br />
        <label style="text-align: center;" id="topleftimgdescr">Vakantiepark de &ldquo;Krieghuusbelten&rdquo;</label>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;">
        <img id="maxwifilogo" src="http://placehold.it/175x75/cc6666/ffffff&text=dompdf"  alt="" /><br />
        <label id="maxwifihref" style="margin-right: 50px;"><a>www.maxCoax.nl</a></label>
  <table>
    <tr style="height: 25px;">
   <td colspan="3">Wifi activationcode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 25px;">
   <td colspan="1">Tijdsduur: </td><td colspan="2" id="timelimit">10080 minuten</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 25px;">
   <td colspan="1">Apparaten: </td><td colspan="2">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 25px; line-height: 12px;">
   <td colspan="1">Activatiecode: </td><td colspan="2" id="vouchercode">PnBndxTvYhu</td>
    </tr>
        </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="instructionsection">
        <div class="partial">
            <div class="countrypng"><img id="nllogo" src="http://placehold.it/60x35/cc6666/ffffff&text=dompdf" alt="" /><span class="countrytext">NL</span></div>
            <div class="instruction">
                <b>Instructies</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    Start uw notebook, PDA of PC. Wanneer u binnen het bereik van een wifi hotspot bent kunt u verbinding<br />
                    maken met het Wifi netwerk. Start internet en de activatiepagina opent.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Vul de hierboven vermelde toegangscode in.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        De tijdsduurgebruik gaat in na activatie.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        U kunt gebruik maken van internet.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <b>Let op!</b> Deze toegangscode is te activeren op 1 apparaat.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="partial">
            <div class="countrypng"><img id="enlogo" src="http://placehold.it/60x35/cc6666/ffffff&text=dompdf" alt="" /><span class="countrytext">EN</span></div>
            <div class="instruction">
                <b>Instructions</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    Start up your notebook, PDA or PC. Please connect with the Wifi network if you are within range of a Wifi access point.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Log on to the internet. You will land on the activation page.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Enter the above mentioned access code. The duration of use starts after activation.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        You are now ready to use internet.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <b>Attention!</b> This code is for use on 1 device
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="partial">
            <div class="countrypng"><img id="delogo" src="http://placehold.it/60x35/cc6666/ffffff&text=dompdf" alt="" /><span class="countrytext">&nbsp;D</span></div>
            <div class="instruction">
                <b>Hinweise</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    Starten Sie Ihr Notebook, PDA oder Ihren PC. Wenn Sie sich innerhald der Reichweite eines Accespoints befinden,<br />
                    dan k&ouml;nnen Sie mit dem drahlosen Netzwerk verbindung machen.<!--haha, machen! -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Starten Sie internet. Sie bekommen den Aktivierungsseite.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Geben Sie den oben erw&auml;hnten Aktivierungscode ein. Die Dauerder Anwenung startet nach den Aktivierung.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Sie k&ouml;nnen jetzt das Internet benutzen.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <b>Achtung<!-- ik ga helemaal stuk hier!-->!</b> Dieser code k&ouml;nnen sie gleichzeitig aktiveren f&uuml;r den Einsatz auf 1 Ger&auml;t.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pagebreak" class="partial">
            <div class="countrypng"><img id="frlogo" src="http://placehold.it/60x35/cc6666/ffffff&text=dompdf" alt="" /><span class="countrytext">FR</span></div>
            <div class="instruction">
                <b>Instructions</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    Ouvrez Votre portable, PDA ou PC. Lorsque vous &ecirc;tes dans les environs d&rsquo;un point d&rsquo;acc&egrave;s Wifi, vous serez reli&eacute;s<br />
                    apr&egrave;s quelques secondes automatique au r&eacute;sea Wifi systeme sans fil.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        D&eacute;marrez internet. Alors sur le site du hotel ou camping.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Compl&eacute;tez le code d&rsquo;acc&egrave;s mentionn&eacute; ci-dessus. La dur&eacute;e d&rsquo;utilisation commence apr&egrave;s l&rsquo;activation.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Vous pourrez maintenant utiliser internet.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <b>Attention!</b> Ce code est utilis&eacute; sur 1 p&egrave;riph&egrave;rique
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Notes: There were a few spelling errors and incorrect selectors which I tried to correct. Also, I wasn't sure what you were going for in some of your layout choices, so I just made a decision in those instances.